# Add the Case to Parent case based on Email Id or case Status using Workflow/Process builder

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, visual-workflow

Suppose i have case in salesforce **Case1** and email Id-abc@gmail.com
Now second Case is Created **case2** and email id -abc@gmail
Another case is created **case3** and email id-abc@gmail.com

So,
Case1-->abc@gmail.com
Case2-->abc@gmail.com
Case3-->abc@gmail.com

**Parent Case -->**Case1**
Child Cases -->**Case2** & **Case3****

Comment: Is there any way to your requirement that the email-Id will change?

Comment: may be it will get change but no requirement as of now

Comment: If that's the case then you can create a process builder and call apex class (i.e invocable method). Otherwise, create a process builder and call flow (It will query the existing record and reparent the same)

Comment: Is there any sample coder/flow available as i am new to flow

Comment: I can provide you the snippets for creating same. Though, they will work smoothly if email-Id on case record won't be changed.

Comment: Is this not achievable using only Process Builder?

Answer (score 0):

As you requirement is not very clear. However, on your request I am providing you the snippets to give some idea about how you can achieve the same by creating process builder and flow. This solution will work smoothly if email id on case record in not edited. PSB screenshots for same. 
[image]

[image]

***Notes** : If the case email-Id is edited then create an apex class and call the same from above process builder. It will help you to handle complex logic. Because, the re-parenting for same would be bit complex to handle using flow.

Comment: Can u please also let me know the insider things in flow element .Like how you have configured  elements